# Merge one tensor into other tensor on specific indexes in PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

Any efficient way to merge one tensor to another in Pytorch, but on specific indexes.

Here is my full problem.

I have a list of indexes of a `tensor` in below code `xy` is the original tensor.
**I need to preserve the rows** (those rows who are in indexes list) of `xy`  and apply some function on elements other than those indexes (For simplicity let say the function is 'multiply them with two),

```
xy = torch.rand(100,4)
indexes=[1,2,55,44,66,99,3,65,47,88,99,0]
```

Then merge them back into the original tensor.

This is what I have done so far:
I create a mask tensor

```
indexes=[1,2,55,44,66,99,3,65,47,88,99,0]
xy = torch.rand(100,4)
mask=[]
for i in range(0,xy.shape[0]):
    if i in indexes: 
         mask.append(False)  
    else:
        mask.append(True)
print(mask)
import numpy as np
target_mask = torch.from_numpy(np.array(mask, dtype=bool))
print(target_mask.sum()) #output is 89 as these are element other than preserved.
```

Apply the function on masked rows

```
zy = xy[target_mask]
print(zy)
zy=zy*2
print(zy)
```

**Code above is working fine and posted here to clarify the problem**

Now I want to merge tensor `zy` into `xy` on specified index saved in the list `indexes`.
Here is the pseudocode I made, as one can see it is too complex and need 3 for loops to complete the task. and it will be too much resources wastage.

```
# pseudocode
for masked_row in indexes: 
    for xy_rows_index in xy: 
        if xy_rows_index= masked_row
            pass
        else:
            take zy tensor row and replace here #another loop to read zy.
```

But I am not sure what is an efficient way to merge them, as I don't want to use `NumPy` or `for` loop etc. It will make the process slow, as the original tensor is too big and I am going to use GPU.

Any efficient way in Pytorch for this?

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly `indexes` is just a tensor of indices right? Wouldn't just using `zy = xy[indexes]` work?

Comment: yes. it is working fine. question is for the last portion I wrote as sudo code. above code is working fine.

Comment: Ah I misread the first paragraph, I think i understand now.

Comment: I added more information to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have your mask you can assign updated values in place.

```py
zy = 2 * xy[target_mask]
xy[target_mask] = zy
```

As for acquiring the mask I don't see a problem necessarily with your approach, though using the built-in set operations would probably be more efficient. This also gives an index tensor instead of a mask, which, depending on the number of indices being updated, may be more efficient.

```py
i = list(set(range(len(xy)))-set(indexes))
zy = 2 * xy[i]
xy[i] = zy
```

**Edit:**

To address the comment, specifically to find the complement of indices of `i` we can do

```py
i_complement = list(set(range(len(xy)))-set(i))
```

However, assuming `indexes` contains only values between `0` and `len(xy)-1` then we could equivalently use `i_complement = len(set(indexes))`, which just removes the repeated values in `indexes`.

Comment: I did not accept the answer as I was verifying this with different combinations. 
What if I want to reverse this i = list(set(range(len(xy)))-set(indexes)), true to false and false to true? if you update the answer I will accept it. or either you remove it. in both cases I will accept it. Thanks for your reply any way.

Comment: @AdnanAli I believe that the most recent edit addresses your concern.